# Asyncio Sockets, Localhost vs local IP

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, python-asyncio

I have an Asyncio script I'm writing. Everything is working but I had a question about what I'm seeing in a tuple asyncio returns as the address.

This line of code returns two different things depending on weather I connect with a client using localhost or my local IP address.

```
(Server code)
addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
print("Received %r from %r" % (message, addr))
```

With localhost as my connection in my client, I see this on my server

```
(Client code)
reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('localhost', 8888, loop=asyncloop)

(Server prints)
Received 'Hello World!' from ('::1', 50402, 0, 0)
```

And with an IP address as my connection in my client,

```
(Client code)
reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('192.168.147.200', 8888, loop=asyncloop)

(Server prints)
Received 'Hello World!' from ('192.168.147.139', 50313)
```

What are the meanings of the two zero's in the first tuple? And why aren't they there when I connect with an IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#socket-families

Your localhost connection is arriving via IPv6:

> For `AF_INET6` address family, a four-tuple `(host, port, flowinfo, scopeid)` is used, where *flowinfo* and *scopeid* represent the `sin6_flowinfo` and `sin6_scope_id` members in `struct sockaddr_in6` in C. For `socket` module methods, *flowinfo* and *scopeid* can be omitted just for backward compatibility. Note, however, omission of *scopeid* can cause problems in manipulating scoped IPv6 addresses.

Your explicit IP address connection is an IPv4 connection, for which:

> A pair `(host, port)` is used for the `AF_INET` address family, where *host* is a string representing either a hostname in Internet domain notation like 'daring.cwi.nl' or an IPv4 address like '100.50.200.5', and *port* is an integer.

The hostname `'localhost'` can be resolved to either an IPv6 or IPv4 address, whereas `'192.168.147.200'` is an explicit IPv4 address.

Answer (score 0):

Additional fields seems to be related about the [IPv6 address scoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Global_addressing).

See also [socket.getnameinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getnameinfo) and [socket.getpeername](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getpeername).